# There is a missing attribute in the chromosome in genetic algorithm

Tags: random, initialization, genetic-algorithm, mutation

I'm building a model about airline scheduling by using genetic algorithms that generate a flight schedule on a daily basis and assigning the right aircraft too. Each chromosome represents a total of 50 flight legs a day(including the return trip that means 100 trips a day) and I have 42 legs, so obviously there will be repeated flight legs.
The initial members are created randomly, and there are some constraints that must be satisfied to have a valid schedule. The problem is one of the constraints is that all flight legs must be included, but the model always fails to achieve that!! It starts by missing like 9 or 10 destinations, then it decreases by using creep mutation until it reaches 1 and gets stuck in it and never finds it! Even when it runs for 1000 generations!
I tried to interference in the initial member and include them all before the beginning but that doesn't work either! so what's the matter?! how could I solve this?

The fitness code is viewed below, it's still under modifications so I'm sorry if it looks like a little dumb

```py
def fitness (df, df2, member):
    fit = []
    c1, c2, c3, c4, c5 = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    fitgene = []

    for i in range (0,len(df2.index)):
        df2.loc[i, ['Duration']] = 0

    for i in range (0, len(member)-1):
        #Range of aircraft
        acindex = df2[df2['NO']== member[i][4]].index.item()
        acrange = df2['Range'].iloc[acindex]

        findex = df[df['NO']== member[i][0]].index.item()
        distance = df['Distance'].iloc[findex]

        if acrange < distance:
            c1 += 1

        #Duration of aircraft 
        acspeed = df2['Speed'].iloc[acindex]
        time = (distance/acspeed) * 2
        if time < 11:
            df2.loc[acindex, ['Duration']] += time

        for j in range (i+1, len(member)):   

            #same flight at the same time
            if member[i][0] == member [j][0]:
                if member[i][2] == member [j][2]:
                    c2 += 1  

            #same aircraft in flight          
            if member[i][4] == member [j][4]:
                acindex = df2[df2['NO']== member[i][4]].index.item()
                findex = df[df['NO']== member[i][0]].index.item()
                distance = df['Distance'].iloc[findex]    
                acspeed = df2['Speed'].iloc[acindex]
                hour = int(distance/acspeed*2)
                minute = round(((distance/acspeed*2)-hour) * 60)
                #turnaroud time
                trt= df2['TRT'].iloc[acindex]*2   
                hour = hour + member[i][2]
                minute = minute + trt + member[i][3]
                if minute >= 60  :     
                    while(minute >= 60):
                        if minute == 60:
                            minute=0
                        elif minute > 60:
                            minute = minute - 60           
                        hour = hour + 1                 
                start1 = (convert([member[i][2], member[i][3]]))
                end1 = (convert([hour, int(minute)]))

                hour, minute = 0, 0
                acindex = df2[df2['NO']== member[j][4]].index.item()
                findex = df[df['NO']== member[j][0]].index.item()
                distance = df['Distance'].iloc[findex]    
                acspeed = df2['Speed'].iloc[acindex]
                hour = int(distance/acspeed*2)
                minute = round(((distance/acspeed*2)-hour) * 60)
                #turnaroud time
                trt= df2['TRT'].iloc[acindex]*2   
                hour = hour + member[j][2]
                minute = minute + trt + member[j][3]
                if minute >= 60  :     
                    while(minute >= 60):
                        if minute == 60:
                            minute=0
                        elif minute > 60:
                            minute = minute - 60           
                        hour = hour + 1                 
                start2 = (convert([member[j][2], member[j][3]]))
                end2 = (convert([hour, int(minute)]))
                if (start1 <= start2 and start2 <= end1) or (start1 <= end2 and end2 <= end1) or (start2 <= start1 and start1 <= end2) or (start2 <= end1 and end1 <= end2):
                    c3 += 1

    #all flights present in schedule               
    for i in range(0,len(df.index)):
        flight =  df['NO'].iloc[i]
        test = 0
        for j in range(0,len(member)):
            if flight == member[j][0]:
                test = 1
        if test == 0:
            c4 +=1

    #duration 
    for i in range (0,len(df2.index)):
        dur = df2['Duration'].iloc[i]
        if dur > 11:
            c5+=1

    fit.append(c1)
    fit.append(c2)
    fit.append(c3)
    fit.append(c4)
    fit.append(c5)

    fits = c1+c2+c3+c4+c5

    return fits,fit
```

Comment: So you have 42 legs that must be included, and only 8 that are unrestricted. The chromosomes should only include those 8. In other words, the chromosomes should represent choices. If there's no choice for a particular parameter, then it doesn't belong in the chromosome.

Comment: Why? I included all of them because for every flight the model must find the right flight time and the right aircraft too.

Comment: Ok, so the choices for those 42 legs are the flight time, and the aircraft. So you have 42 elements of the chromosome that are (flight time, aircraft), and 8 elements that are (leg, flight time, aircraft).

Comment: exactly! but I can't control the process of choosing the flight legs, all choice must done randomly

Comment: Well then you have two options. 1) Tweak the fitness function so that it's based almost entirely on the number of legs, e.g. `1000 * legCount + other` where `other` is always less than 1000. 2) Tweak the crossover function so that it always includes at least one copy of every unique leg in both parents. For example, if one parent has chromosome ABCBCC and the other parent has BCDDCB, then the crossover function guarantees that the offspring is ABCDxx (where `x` represents any leg found in the parents).

Comment: Okay, I think the second one might work, I'm using PMX crossover but I'll see how I can adjust it. But, I prefer to find another way that doesn't affect the selection or crossover method so could you please explain the first one again, I didn't understand it.

Comment: It would help if you posted your current fitness function.

Comment: It's too long to be posted in a comment here.. I would really appreciate it if you send me a message on my email (hberkawi@gmail.com) so you could check it

Comment: You can [edit] the function into the question itself. If necessary, you can omit some parts to simplify it. See [mcve].

Comment: It looks like `c4` is the part of the fitness that indicates how many of the 42 legs are covered. So to emphasize that portion of the fitness, change `c4+=1` to `c4+=10` or `c4+=1000`.

Comment: Okay, it's clear now! I'll try it and hope it works.